# Prestashop module route for images

Tags: routes, module, prestashop

I created this hook with two routes:

```
    public function hookModuleRoutes()
    {
        if (empty($this->alias)) {
            return [];
        }

        $routes = [
            'module-resizer-generateimage' => [
                'controller' => 'generateimage',
                'rule' => $this->alias,
                'keywords' => [
                ],
                'params' => [
                    'fc' => 'module',
                    'module' => 'resizer',
                ],
            ],
            'module-resizer-generateimagequery' => [
                'controller' => 'generateimage',
                'rule' => $this->alias.'/{query}',
                'keywords' => [
                    'query' => ['regexp' => '.+', 'param' => 'query'],
                ],
                'params' => [
                    'fc' => 'module',
                    'module' => 'resizer',
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $routes;
    }
```

With this setup those URLs work:

- https://example.com/generateimage
- https://example.com/generateimage/abcd

I expect those URLs should also work:

- https://example.com/generateimage/abcd.jpg
- https://example.com/generateimage/abcd.png
- https://example.com/generateimage/folder/abcd.jpg
- https://example.com/generateimage/folder/subfolder/abcd.png

but they don't. With those URLs I see the Prestashop 404 page.

I just need **anything** after "/generateimage/" to be passed to my frontcontoller as a keyword. Any help, please?

Comment: In the class `DispatcherCore`, in the method `getController()`, you can find this comment : `If the request_uri matches a static file, then there is no need to check the routes, we keep "controller_not_found" (a static file should not go through the dispatcher)`

Which means that without any override of this class, you won't be able to achieve what you want. However i do not recommend to do so but instead you could add a segment in your route for the expected extension for example.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the query to be passed as a GET parameter and now it works as I need.